# How to build a basic mnist neural net using tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to build a neural network model using tensorflow 2.0 and I couldn't find anything online on how to do it in tensorflow 2.0

I've tried but I couldn't figure out how to apply gradients and all etc..

Here's what's I've tried,

```
import math
import tensorflow as tf

(x_train,y_train),(x_test,y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

x_train = tf.reshape(x_train,shape=(60000,28*28))
x_test = tf.reshape(x_test,shape=(10000,28*28))

x_train = tf.cast(x_train, tf.float32)
x_test = tf.cast(x_test, tf.float32)

n_input = 784
h1 = 512
h2 = 128
n_classes = 10

# weights and bias initializations
f1 = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform(shape = (n_input,h1), minval = -(math.sqrt(6)/math.sqrt(n_input+h1)),  
                            maxval = (math.sqrt(6)/math.sqrt(n_input+h1)))) # Xavier uniform
f2 = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform(shape = (h1,h2), minval = -(math.sqrt(6)/math.sqrt(h1+h2)),
                             maxval = (math.sqrt(6)/math.sqrt(h1+h2)))) 
out = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform(shape = (h2,n_classes), minval = -(math.sqrt(6/(h2+n_classes))),
                                   maxval = math.sqrt(6/(h2+n_classes)) ))

b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform([h1]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform([h2]))
b_out = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform([n_classes]))

def mlp(x):
  input1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, f1), b1))
  input2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(input1, f2), b2))  
  output = tf.nn.softmax(tf.add(tf.matmul(input2, out), b_out))
  return output

n_shape = x_train.shape[0]
epochs = 2
batch_size = 128
lr_rate = 0.001

data_gen = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train)).repeat().shuffle(n_shape).batch(batch_size)

def grad(x, y):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    y_pred = mlp(x)
    loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=y_pred)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)
    return tape.gradient(loss, [w, b])

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr_rate)

for _ in range(epochs):
  no_steps = int(60000/128)
  for (batch_xs, batch_ys) in data_gen.take(no_steps):
```

I just can't figure out how to proceed further in this case? I would really appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials on the TF website, why don't you just look at those?

Comment: @xdurch0 I couldn't find any with custom implementation. All the examples I've found was using keras sequential API. If you found any please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are following problems in your code:

- You forgot to rescale your data:  `x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0`
- `w` and `b` in line: `tape.gradient(loss, [w, b])` are not defined.
- Valid `labels` dtype in `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` should be `int32` or `int64`, while for `logits`, it should be `float16`, `float32`, or `float64`. In your case, it's `uint8` for labels. Convert it to `int32` before passing, like below

  `loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf.cast(y, dtype=tf.int32), logits=y_pred)`
- As per the official documentation,

  > WARNING: This op expects unscaled logits, since it performs a softmax
  >   on logits internally for efficiency. Do not call this op with the
  >   output of softmax, as it will produce incorrect results.

  So, remove `tf.nn.softmax` from the output of `mlp` function, as it performs `softmax` on `logits` internally.

  For more info on `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`, check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits).

You should  modify your `grad` function and `For` loop to something like below:

```
def grad(x, y):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    y_pred = mlp(x)
    loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf.cast(y, dtype=tf.int32), logits=y_pred)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)
    return loss, tape.gradient(loss, [f1, b1, f2, b2, out, b_out])

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr_rate)

for epoch in range(epochs):
  no_steps = n_shape//batch_size
  for (batch_xs, batch_ys) in data_gen.take(no_steps):
    cost, grads = grad(batch_xs, batch_ys)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, [f1, b1, f2, b2, out, b_out]))
  print('epoch: {} loss: {}'.format(epoch, cost))
```

Comment: Thank you ! Apart from these did I do everything correctly? Don't we have to do back propagation?

Comment: Welcome. In order to get clear idea on this thing, go through this https://adventuresinmachinelearning.com/tensorflow-eager-tutorial/

Comment: Just one doubt . I hope you can clear it. We are initializing weights with f1, f2, out right but we are only applying gradients to optimizer but we are not updating our variables f1, f2 and out? For future predicting or to calculate loss how does it work?

Comment: `tape.gradient(loss, [f1, b1, f2, b2, out, b_out])` will give you gradients of loss w.r.t. model weights and `optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, [f1, b1, f2, b2, out, b_out]))` is actually updating the model weights.

Comment: As at the end, you will have the learned weights. you can use it for prediction same as you do with other models.

Comment: Can you please update the code on how to print loss and accuracy per epoch. Cuz after first loop and we get leaned weights and during second epoch we will again call MLP function right? In that we will again access weights from variables f1, f2 and so on right? I couldn't get how it works.

Comment: It's confusing in the colab notebook. can you please post it in the above answer?

Comment: Check I updated the code. Added loss printing after each epoch.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can't understand how is works? For every epoch and for every batch we will keep calling grad function ? Now in this grad function we will keep calling MLP function which I wrote above right? In MLP we are doing tf.matmul(x, f1) right? Here f1 is  not updating then how does it work? We will have the same f1 right? I can't understand it intuitively.

Comment: Loss is calculated for each batch but I am printing only the last one, i.e., loss for last batch of each epoch. After loss is calculated every time, weights are updated using `optimizer.apply_gradients` function. `grad` function is just calculating loss and gradients w.r.t. variable but not updating it. Weights are finally updated inside `For` loop.

Comment: Do you know how can I add a dropout layer into this neural net model? Do I have to compute weights for dropout layer as well?